# Is it mandatory to name groups and folders in English?

Tags: ios

When we create a group or folder in Xcode, must we name the group or folder in English?

I heard about all the people saying yes, but my master told me that we can use Chinese (another language) name groups or folder, too. So now I am a little confused about this. Is there any hidden danger when we use Chinese? Could anyone tell me the truth and the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in past I've builded a project entirely in italian without any problem, and I'm speaking about Xcode 5.

However you can find official documents [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW3)

And you can find also the support to Right-to-Left and Left-to-Right language [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH17-SW1).

---

**P.S**. If you want to change entirely language to add some charset, look the Apple official instruction to do it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SpecifyingPreferences/SpecifyingPreferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH12-SW1)

Comment: 可以，很强势（nice ，very mighty）